# How do I scrape across this dynamic table?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, dynamic

As an exercise I tried scraping the info in the secondary links from the table on this [main page](https://www.employbl.com/company-locations/los-angeles), but couldn't get past the first 100 items of the table.

This is the code I used:

```
`import pandas as pd
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

`# Function to scrape individual company pages

def scrape_company_info(company_url):
company_data = {}
company_page = requests.get(company_url)
company_soup = BeautifulSoup(company_page.text, 'html.parser')

    try:
        # Extract company information
        company_data['Company Name'] = company_soup.find('h1', class_='mt-3').text.strip()
        company_data['Location'] = company_soup.find('p', class_='mt-3 text-xl italic text-gray-500').text.strip()
        company_data['Description'] = company_soup.find('p', class_='mt-3 mb-1').text.strip()
    
        # Find the website link
        website_link = company_soup.find('a', class_='flex items-center justify-center text-base font-medium text-indigo-600 sm:justify-start')
        if website_link:
            company_data['Website'] = website_link['href']
    
        # Find the additional company information
        company_info_dl = company_soup.find('dl', class_='grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 px-6 pb-6 sm:grid-cols-2')
        if company_info_dl:
            for dt, dd in zip(company_info_dl.find_all('dt', class_='text-base font-medium text-gray-500'),
                              company_info_dl.find_all('dd', class_='text-3xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900')):
                company_data[dt.find('h2').text] = dd.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(f"Skipping company due to AttributeError: {company_url}")
        return None
    
    return company_data`

`# Initialize an empty list to store the scraped data

data = {}`

`# Loop through the main page and scrape data

while True:
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find all company rows
    company_rows = soup.find_all('tr', role='row')
    
    for row in company_rows:
        company_link = row.find('a', class_='underline hover:text-tangelo')
        if company_link:
            company_url = 'https://www.employbl.com' + company_link['href']
            print(f"Scraping company: {company_link.text}")
            company_info = scrape_company_info(company_url)
            if company_info:
                data.append(company_info)
    
    # Find the "Next" button to navigate to the next page
    next_button = soup.find('button', class_='relative inline-flex items-center border border-gray-300 bg-white px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50')
    if next_button and 'disabled' not in next_button.attrs.get('class', []):
        url = 'https://www.employbl.com' + next_button.parent['href']
    else:
        break`

    `# Create a DataFrame from the collected data

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)`
```

I was able to get the first 100 items but failed to iterate to the next page because the next button doesn't actually go to a new url but updates the page dynamically. How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT or other AI to generate this code?

Comment: Yes, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Information on the page is stored in the script block with ID '**NEXT_DATA**'. So just get the required fields, and save it to dataframe

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

data = []
response = requests.get('https://www.employbl.com/company-locations/los-angeles')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
companies = json.loads(soup.find('script', {'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).get_text())
for company in companies['props']['pageProps']['companyCollection']:
    data.append({'Name': company['name'], 'Description': company['description'], 'Location': company['hq_location']})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
                                  Name  ...         Location
0                         LighthouseAI  ...  Los Angeles, CA
1                            Plai Labs  ...  Los Angeles, CA
2                      D'Amelio Brands  ...  Los Angeles, CA
3                              Muverse  ...  Los Angeles, CA
4                                 APEX  ...  Los Angeles, CA
...                                ...  ...              ...
1118                  My-Minuteman.com  ...  Los Angeles, CA
1119  The Barnes Firm Injury Attorneys  ...  Los Angeles, CA
1120                        AntEye.com  ...  Los Angeles, CA
1121                           Imaggly  ...  Los Angeles, CA
1122                        FITS.cloud  ...  Los Angeles, CA
```

If you need extra fields, in loop do requests to full company info, and get everything you need

```
for company in companies['props']['pageProps']['companyCollection']:
    full_info = requests.get(f"https://www.employbl.com/_next/data/{companies['buildId']}/en/companies/{company['slug']}.json?company={company['slug']}").json()['pageProps']['companyInfo']['company']
    data.append({'Year founded': full_info['year_founded'], 'Website': full_info['website'], 'Linkedin': full_info['linkedin_uri']})
```

For example 'Year founded', 'website' and 'Linkedin':

```
  Year founded            Website                               Linkedin
0         2023   lighthouseai.com      linkedin.com/company/lighthouseai
1         2023       plailabs.com         linkedin.com/company/plai-labs
2         2022    thedamelios.com     linkedin.com/company/dameliobrands
3         2022  muverse.info/home                                   None
4         2022      apexspace.com          linkedin.com/company/apexvape
5         2022      solsniper.xyz                                   None
6         2022  cabrasportshq.com      linkedin.com/company/cabra-sports
7         2022       ucladevx.com         linkedin.com/company/ucla-devx
8         2022         blaze.tech  linkedin.com/company/blaze-technology
9         2022      goldenset.com         linkedin.com/company/goldenset
```